# Serial Communication Arduino Python - type conversion

Tags: python, arduino, type-conversion, pyserial

Before I start: Yes, I know there are a lot of similar questions, and I really tried to solve the problem by myself with those themes. I am an absolute newbie at python.

My problem is that I want to read out a serial communication between an Arduino and Python.

I am doing it with `import serial` and it works fine. I can get the values with Python. But now I have a big problem: I am sending double values. In my example, I'm sending three double values to the USB interface.
In Python, they are looking like (one of them):

```
[b'\x00', b'H', b'\x93', b'@', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00']
```

I read each of the 8 bytes over a loop.
Now I want to convert them into a float again (like a number like 58).

I've tried a lot. There are some approaches in my code, but I am lost at the moment. I am getting a `<class 'list'>` at the moment, but I don't think that is the best way. Does someone have an idea for my next steps? Thanks.

```
import serial
#import struct
#import sys
#import numpy

#byte_groesse = numpy.arange(0,7)

byte_groesse = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=1)
ser.flushInput()

try: 

    while True:
    
    for i in range(0,8):
        byte_groesse[i] = ser.read()
                                        
    if i == 7:
              
       print(type(byte_groesse))
       print(" \n", byte_groesse)   
       
       #TESTS
       
       #xy = struct.unpack('f', byte_groesse) # TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
       #lapply(byte_groesse, as.numpy)
       #test = as.numeric(unlist(byte_groesse))
       #xy = map(float,byte_groesse)
       #print(type(byte_groesse))
       #a = struct.unpack('f', byte_groesse)
       #wert = struct.unpack('!d', xy)
```

Comment: Your `byte_groesse` is a python list, in order to use `struck.unpack()` you need a bytes-like object, that is  a `bytearray`, so it should be `struct.unpack('d', bytearray(byte_groesse))`.

Comment: Be aware of the concept of [Endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), your PC might be big endian, while Arduino is a little endian system. You may need to a conversion before unpack to get the right number.